# How to avoid render if the output is same in UseState hooks in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react , for learning i created a simple incrementor , i used object as input instead of simple string or number , whenever i clicked increment , it render the component due to change in value and then i click reset button it set count to 0.

But for curiosity , i clicked multiple times a reset render , it render every time even there is no change in dom. As of i know it render because the object was created newly every time.
How to stop the render when i click reset button multiple times?

```
import { Fragment, useReducer, useRef, useState,useMemo, useEffect } from "react"

export default function Sample()
{ 
   const [num,setnum]=useState({count:0})
   const inc =()=>{
   setnum((prevstate)=>({...num,count:prevstate.count+1}))
   }
   const reset =()=>{
    console.log("render")
    setnum({...num,count:0})
   }
   return(
    <div>
       <button>{num.count}</button>
       <button onClick={inc}>Increment</button>
       <button onClick={reset}>reset</button>
    </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: You're logging "render" in the `reset` function, not when your component is rendering

Comment: You shouldn't worry too much about re-renders, especially in this case. Re-renders are relatively cheap, as no costly DOM updates will happen. Also, re-renders in this case will only happen when the user clicks the reset button. It's hardly the case that someone will keep pressing the reset button when the counter is 0. Nevertheless, you can implement a simple check to see if the counter is > 0 in order to set the state inside the reset() as the answers below indicate.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the reset like below :

```
const reset =()=> {
    console.log("render")
    if(num.count){ setnum({...num,count:0})}      
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Calling the setter from the useState Hook will always trigger a rerender.

If you want to prevent this, you can check if the count is already reset and don't call it.

```
import { Fragment, useReducer, useRef, useState,useMemo, useEffect } from "react"

export default function Sample()
{
    
   const [num,setnum]=useState({count:0})
   const inc =()=>{
   setnum((prevstate)=>({...num,count:prevstate.count+1}))
   }
   const reset = () => {
    console.log("render")
    if (num !== 0) {
    setnum({...num,count:0})
    }
   }
   return(
    <div>
    <button>{num.count}</button>
    <button onClick={inc}>Increment</button>
    <button onClick={reset}>reset</button>
    </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: calling the setter doesn't automatically trigger a render. React won't rerender if the same object reference or primitive value as the current state is passed. see [Bailing out of state update](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)

Comment: New documentation [setState: Caveats](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-caveats)